# hg: unknown command 'qimportbz'

Tags: mercurial, mozilla, bugzilla

I followed [the instructions on how to setup qimportbz here](http://robarnold.org/hg-qimport-my-bugzilla-patch-redux/); I'm on WinXP and instead of adding:

```
[extensions]
qimportbz = C:\mozilla\mercurial\qimportbz
```

to a `.hgrc` file I updated a `Mercurial.ini` file which seems to be the correct file to add extensions to for me..

then when I run `hg help qimportbz` I see the help for the `qimportbz` cmd, but when I try to run `hg qimportbz 548590` for example, on the [jetpack-sdk hg repo](http://hg.mozilla.org/labs/jetpack-sdk/), I get the following error:

```
hg: unknown command 'qimportbz'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem. I believe the syntax has changed. Try `hg qimport bz://bug_num` where *bug_num*  is the bugzilla bug id.

Comment: This is correct:
http://hg.mozilla.org/users/robarnold_cmu.edu/qimportbz/file/14e99b1f1ff9/__init__.py#l5

Answer (score 0):

Try instead to declare the extension in your `<repo>/.hg/hgrc` file, just to check if that has any influence on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What does your `hg debugconfig` show?  Any mention of qmimportbz?  There's a chance you need double backslashes each time you use them, but the output of debugconfig should make that clear if it's the case.

FWIW either .hgrc or Mercurial.ini will work for you.  On unix-alikes only .hgrc is checked, but on Windows both are.  See the hgrc man page for details on that.